# How to build a project Visual Studio can run cross-platform

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, project

I have a project C/C++ in Visual Studio. I have some trouble: 
How can i build release version which can run in Linux and MacOSX, of course it have to run in Window.

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You code it for platform independence, and *build* it for each platform. (and note: platform independence does *not* mean slamming `#ifdef SOME_PLATFORM` all over your code base). Ideally there is *none* of that unless absolutely no other option exists (ex: dynamic module loading).

Comment: so how can I take my code cross-platform if i start from scratch.

Comment: Don't make any assumptions about platform architecture, and make it a mission to *minimize* code that is platform-*dependent*. The example I gave about dynamic module loading (DLL's, shared-objects, dylibs, etc.) is an sample where such code is unavoidable, but your mission is to make that the exception; not commonplace. Take the time to learn more of the standard libs, particularly the C++11 standard if you choose that language. It is an *incredibly* powerful library, and is standard-backed.

Answer (score 0):

cmake is a usefull tool to complie program write by C/C++,as well as other,recommend you to use.
for how to write a program which could run everywhere,I am considering you need to read some open source project,this is a good start.